# Mounting fails with fstab

Tags: linux, debian, fstab

I am trying to create a mount point that remains persistent on reboot by adding the following line into `/etc/fstab`

`/ownCloud/admin/files/Website\ Backups/ /home/example/Backups none bind 0 0`

This is the command I run to mount it manually

`mount --bind /ownCloud/admin/files/Website\ Backups/ /home/example/Backups`

The directory never gets mounted on reboot though. I don't see any errors in the log files so I am having a hard time troubleshooting the problem. Hoping someone can help me out on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be something to do w/ the space (" ") in the path. I would first try a directory w/ out space in fstab and see if that works on reboot. I have a bind mount entry on my fstab, and it gets mounted on reboot as expected. The only difference is that I don't have space.

Comment: You were right, I did a search on Google for `fstab with space` and came up with this [link](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2287-fstab-adding-spaces-in-the-mount-point-path) it says to use `\040` instead of spaces in mount paths.